# Android - RTSP Streaming from Camera and view from remote location

Tags: android, rtsp, live-streaming, libstreaming, rtsp-server

I Want to create an Android app that will have the functionality to stream camera over the RTSP on my public IP address, and it can be viewed by anyone with whom I'll share my IP address using the RTSP URL.

RTSP Stream URL:  "rtsp://${ANDROID_DEVICE_PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS}:${PORT}/"

I've tried numerous solution that are being offered by all the libraries:

- https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming/tree/master/src/net/majorkernelpanic/streaming
- https://github.com/pedroSG94/RootEncoder
- Any Many more